# API to post messages on Diaspora 0.7.*

Tags: php, api, curl, diaspora

I've developped an API to post message on Diaspora. Everything works well on Diaspora 1.*. But when I try on Diaspora 0.7, I've the following error: "Page Not Found". So I think I am calling the wrong url. I did some research and couldn't find the right URL but I managed to get the `access_token`. Here is my code:

```
$DIASPORA_FR_URL = "https://diasporabr.com.br/";

$accessToken = "my_access_token";

$url = "{$DIASPORA_FR_URL}api/v1/posts?access_token=$accessToken";

$params = [
    "body" => "test",
    "public" => true
];

$data = http_build_query($params);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    $result = curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

How to adapt this code to work with Diaspora 0.7.*?

Comment: From my understanding Diaspora is a federated service which means that different servers may have different versions installed.  I doubt whether a particular server will have multiple versions installed.  According to your post you have $DIASPORA_FR_URL; was this previously a French URL and now you are trying to access a BR Server which has Diaspora 0.7 installed?  Just trying to get some clarity

Comment: I want to reuse my code used for a project where I sent messages on Diaspora 1.*. But it seems that between these two versions there is a difference.

Comment: Do you have access to the code for both versions?  Look at the directory structure of both to see if this part -> api/v1/posts?access_token= is the same in both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API was only really introduced in the currently unreleased next major version of diaspora*, see https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora/blob/develop/Changelog.md

Thus the currently released stable version, 0.7, doesn't feature the API. Only installations running the latest development builds, that is some of the 0.7.99 versions or as you discovered yourself the current 1.0-dev versions support the API.

Comment: I think you're right. I downloaded the source code for this version of Diaspora. Indeed, there is no route to post messages on Diaspora.